# Magento 2 how can to get bank details in order success page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How can i get bank details in order success page when i select in bank payment page and checkout.

Comment: Where did you save the bank details? Paste your code here.

Comment: In admin panel Stores->Configuration->Sales->Payment Methods->OTHER PAYMENT METHODS->Bank Transfer Payment->Instructions
I will add my bank details it should be displayed at order success page

Comment: You will get the payment method code from order on success page then you need to get the method instruction from system config.

Comment: How to method instruction from system config Sukumar Gorai

Comment: Can you paste you system.xml for the payment method? Can you give me the extension url you are using?

Comment: No. I mean you are using magento's default bank payment method right?

Comment: Yeah bank Transfer Payment method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the instruction text of bank transfer by following code:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId());

$payment = $order->getPayment();
$method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
$methodCode = $method->getCode();
if($methodCode == 'banktransfer'){
    $additional = $payment->getAdditionalInformation();
    echo $additional['instructions'];
}
?>
```

You need to put the above code in your **success.phtml** file. You can modify the code according to your requirement also the using of object manager is not a good practice. You can modify it accordingly. I have placed the working code.

Comment: How can show details one after other..

Comment: @SukumarGorai I need to sent this bank details as sms to customer in success page.. please help me for this..